# Convert data inside a list into a given format in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, django-views

I'm trying to get an convert my list into a particular format(expected output), but I'm getting a problem. so I'm trying to order exceptions according to a given time and in a lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str()`, you can use f-string and padding:

`final_tuple = f"{hour1:02}:{min1:02}-{hour2:02}:{min2:02} {data} {exception_count[data])},"`

Comment: f can't be used in my code since i'm using python 3.5

Comment: So I have got time in place but my expected output is still what I want. i.e output to be exact same as expected output @Emmanuel Di Pretoro

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strftime](https://strftime.org/) and format those hours:minutes as "%H:%M"